# ReportProcessingException: query execution failed for dataset

Tags: reporting-services

I created a report and when I try to preview it the following message is displayed :

> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Query execution failed for dataset XXXXX.

I run the query I'm using in the dataset and it works . I used the Query Designer in Dataset Properties and the SQL Server Management Studio. Tested the connections to DataSource and it is created successfully.

It isn't a permissions problem because I created other reports that run without problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are passing any parameters to the dataset? if so and they are multi-valued, check you are handling that correctly. Have you tried executing the query from the dataset query designer directly?

Comment: hi Alan, No, no passing parameters. and yes, I executed the query from the datset designer directly and it works

Comment: Are you using the db name in your queries (dbname.dbo.table)? If not check the data source on the Report Server to make sure it matches what you need. I had a co-worker who overwrote a data source with a different db name and jacked some reports up. Now we **try** to have one data source per server.

Answer (score 0):

In my query I noticed some items had square brackets around them and some didn't.

I put square brackets around all items in the select statement and this error went away.

BEFORE:

```
SELECT [ID], Name, Value
FROM Table
```

AFTER:

```
SELECT [ID], [Name], [Value]
FROM Table
```